# What is the difference between !r and %r in Python?

Tags: python, string, format, string-formatting

As the title states, what is the difference between these two flags? It seems they both convert the value to a string using repr()?
Also, in this line of code:

```
"{0!r:20}".format("Hello")
```

What does the 0 in front of the !r do?

Comment: The 0 means "use the 0th positional argument" - you only need it if you mean to use one of the position arguments more than once or if you need to support Python 2.6. `"{} {}"`.format(...)` gets automatically numbered so as to be treated as `"{0} {1}".format(...)` in Python 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: This can be one of those interview questions no one expects

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`%r` is not a valid placeholder in the `str.format()` formatting operations; it only works in [old-style `%` string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). It indeed converts the object to a representation through the `repr()` function.

In `str.format()`, `!r` is the equivalent, but this also means that you can now use all the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for a string. Normally `str.format()` will call the `object.__format__()` method on the object itself, but by using `!r`, `repr(object).__format__()` is used instead.

There are also the `!s` and (in Python 3) `!a` converters; these apply the `str()` and [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) functions first.

The `0` in front indicates what argument to the `str.format()` method will be used to fill that slot; positional argument `0` is `"Hello"` in your case. You could use *named* arguments too, and pass in objects as keyword arguments:

```
"{greeting!r:20}".format(greeting="Hello")
```

Unless you are using Python 2.6, you can omit this as slots without indices or names are automatically numbered; the first `{}` is `0`, the second `{}` takes the second argument at index `1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify what you meant by "this also means that you can now use all the format codes for a string"?

Comment: The codes after the `:` colon are passed to the `object.__format__()` method and are thus type specific. Floating point numbers accept different formatting codes from strings. Thus if the object  is a float, you'd use different formatting codes from when you add `!r`.